# How do I get capybara to get to the first "yes" item of the table?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
<table class="item-list" id="items">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="item-row">
            <td class="Id">008</td>
            <td class="Surname">Smith</td>
            <td class="Dept">Account</td>
            <td class="Transfer">No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item-row">
            <td class="Id">012</td>
            <td class="Surname">Law</td>
            <td class="Dept">Tech</td>
            <td class="Transfer">Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item-row">
            <td class="Id">015</td>
            <td class="Surname">Thompson</td>
            <td class="Dept">Tech</td>
            <td class="Transfer">No</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need Capybara to get the first 1st  item that has Yes in the Transfer column. 
Not sure how to get the steps definition to go to the particular cell.  In actual fact, the `Yes` in the transfer column is actually a link. How do I get cucumber to click the link? I need to click the first occurrence of `Yes`, the rest doesn't matter.

There's a method as follow:

```
find('//table/tbody/tr').click
```

How do I tell Capybara/Cucumber to search for `"class=Transfer" = "Yes"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
find('.item-row > .transfer', text: 'Yes', match: first).click
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks, I will give it try when I get back in 2 weeks time. :)